# WritingCustomExceptions to EventViewer using SPDiagnosticsservice

Tags: visual-studio-2012, uls

I want to write my customexception to eventviewer , After doing some research I found that I can do that using SPDiagnosticsservice Class. I want to override SPDiagnosticsService and write my customexception

Please help me on how do I start, i am a bit of beginner here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In SharePoint 2010 logging can be done both in ULS and Event Logs
>   using SPDiagnosticsService class. The class provides two methods
>   WriteTrace and WriteEvent to write traces and  events in ULS and Event
>   Viewer respectively. We can also create our own Custom Areas and categories by inheriting  from SPDiagnosticsServiceBase class.

```
public class LoggingService : SPDiagnosticsServiceBase
{
    private const string AREA = "Custom Diagonostic Area";
    private const string CATEGORY = "Custom Diagonostic Category";
    private static readonly LoggingService current;

    public static LoggingService Current
    {
        get
        {
            return LoggingService.current;
        }
    }

    static LoggingService()
    {
        LoggingService.current = new LoggingService();
    }

    private LoggingService()
        : base("Custom Logging Service",SPFarm.Local)
    {
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<SPDiagnosticsArea> ProvideAreas()
    {
        List<SPDiagnosticsArea> areas = new List<SPDiagnosticsArea>
        {
            new SPDiagnosticsArea(LoggingService.AREA, new List<SPDiagnosticsCategory>
            {
                new SPDiagnosticsCategory(LoggingService.CATEGORY,TraceSeverity.Monitorable,EventSeverity.Error)
            })
        };

        return areas;
    }

    public static void LogErrorToULS(TraceSeverity severity, string errorMessage)
    {
        SPDiagnosticsCategory category = LoggingService.Current.Areas[LoggingService.AREA].Categories[LoggingService.CATEGORY];
        LoggingService.Current.WriteTrace(0, category, severity, errorMessage);
    }

    public static void LogErrorToEventViewer(EventSeverity severity, string errorMessage)
    {
        SPDiagnosticsCategory category = LoggingService.Current.Areas[LoggingService.AREA].Categories[LoggingService.CATEGORY];
        LoggingService.Current.WriteEvent(0, category, severity, errorMessage);
    } 
}
```

Please see [SharePoint 2010 Diagnostic logging](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-diagnostic-logging.html) for reference

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the below code....

```
SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("My Category", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
```

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/logging-uls-sharepoint-2010/

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-development/sharepoint-logging-whats-new-sharepoint-2010